# What placeholder names (foobars) to use for types, functions and variables?

Tags: c++, conventions

For the purpose of concept demonstration in c++ I need to use some placeholder naming scheme for types, functions, variables e.g. [Foobar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar). Having several different entities to name and differentiate ending up with foo/bar alone used at the same time for classes, functions, member variables is not visually differentiating. Is there some useful placeholder naming scheme for these entities?

```
enum Enum1 { ... }

struct Struct1 { ... }

class Class1
{
public:
    void function1();
    void function2();
    ...
private:
    int variable1;
    int variable2;
    ...
}
```

With foo/bar alone for types, functions and variables the distinction is not so evident

```
enum Foo { ... }

struct Bar { ... }

class Foo
{
public:
    void foo();
    void bar();
    void baz();
private:
    int foo_;
    int bar_;
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to come up with realistic example. If you can't do that, at least name them in a way that makes it clearer. Even if it's `function1`, `function2`, etc., at least we then know they're functions at a glance. Name things after the role they have in your example.

Comment: naming function1, function2, or foo1, bar2, etc... is not so appealing. is there a common area with large number of named entities for e.g. types? banking area?

Comment: If the question is indeed about teaching, then this should be reflected in the question title and the tags. Explaining OOP concepts to a beginner is quite a specific case. IMHO.

Comment: Also, remember that you can (and should, if applicable) approve an answer even though the question was closed.

Answer (score 2):

Animals are frequently used for illustrating object-oriented programming.  They come with nice homogenous and heterogenous behaviors (`eat`, `bark`), relationship trees (`Dalmatian` is-a `Dog`, `Dog` has-a `Tail`), etc.

Of course, the same problems can be solved via non-OOP techniques... the same attributes then usefully illustrate the relationship between dynamic polymorphism via virtual functions, template specialization, adapters, `enable-if`, etc.

Comment: thanks. OOP is what I'm looking for. animals is suitable

Comment: more leaning towards selection of some realistic area for OOP placeholder naming

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, such examples can suite well to be used to illustrate expressions, syntax or architectural patterns but not algorithms or business logic parts. Whenever you seek to illustrate the last you should really consider using meaningful names explaining their role in the algorithm.

As for me, I usually go with `foo`/`bar`/`moo`/`boo` etc. This does the job quite well *as far as the example is reasonably short*.

If the example is not short enough and the case is that emphasizing on the type (like a function or, say, an array) seems to facilitate readability, `functionA`/`functionB` can be used as an alternative - it seems easier (than with numbers) to read and manipulate such names in mind IMHO. Numbers can distract.

Another way (plays particularly well for me when discussing SQL queries but can be useful in some C++ cases too) is using primitive real-life entities like `class Person` and `class Employee` as a subclass.

If you seek to demonstrate OOP examples to a non-specialist, Foo/Bar/Function1 are absolutely not an option in this case: only the brightest of your students will get the idea then. My first OOP example was a `lightbulb` with `turn on` and `turn off` methods, `isOn` property, `colour` and `power` properties. It can be extended with a `fluorescent` or a `incandescent lamp` subclass and encapsulated in a `desk lamp` class. If you go further in OOP and introduce interfaces it can also implement `ac-powered` and/or `dc-powered` interfaces.

Using Foo/Bar etc. is only relevant when communicating to people of equal or higher experience than of yours - those having full understanding of the language already (e.g when you ask a question like of "should I use `foo + bar` or `foo.plus(bar)`?" kind).

Comment: The `Employee` type hierarchy usually leads to demonstrations of anti-patterns (i.e. trying to put either hourly rate/salary/commission in the base class, when it doesn't apply to all subclasses).  Unfortunately these anti-patterns are often presented in a favorable light.

Comment: yes, more suitable area is needed for demonstration of OOP examples

Comment: If you seek to demonstrate OOP examples to a non-specialist, @ChesnokovYuriy, you should definitely go with Ben's suggestion about the animals. Foo/Bar/Function1 are absolutely not an option in this case: only the brightest of your students will get the idea then. My first OOP example was a lightbulb with turn on and turn off methods, isOn property, colour and power properties. It can be extended with a fluorescent or a incandescent lamp subclass and encapsulated in a desk lamp class. If you go further in OOP and introduce interfaces it can also implement ac-powered and/or dc-powered interf.

Comment: Using Foo/Bar etc. is only relevant when communicating to people of equal or higher experience than of yours - those having full understanding of the language.

Comment: I also think the `method` term should be used instead of a `function` when speaking about an object model.